# Discord.py if not message.content.startswith('') or not message.content.starstwith(''):

Tags: discord.py

How can I write `message.content.startswith('')` with method not and with method or for example:
the problem here is that it doesnt delete the commands that dont start from /start1: or start2:

```py
if not message.content.startswith('/start1:') or not message.content.starstwith('/start2:'):
                await message.delete() 
            else:
                await message.channel.send("working")
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. You can test this, any string will always start with the empty string. You're also just checking `if (not condition) or (not condition)` which will just be `False` every time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Your second `startswith` is not spelt correctly, 'starstwith', so you may have an error thrown at you

Comment: i didnt get an error,its working but not in the way that i want,i need to do a function that will delete all messages that dont starts with command that i wrote.

Comment: You don't get an error cause there is `or` statement. Which if 1 statement corrent, it continue the task

Comment: yes but i want to do the same but with not and with not it doesnt work so it running but it doesnt work in the way that i want(i want that all the messages that i didnt write in the function in: not content.message.startswith('') will delete

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be separated like this..

```
if message.content.startswith("") or message.content.startswith(""):
   await message.channel.send("Working2")
else:
   await message.channel.send("working")
```